# Enabling and disabling controls on a Continuous Subform in Access 2007/2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, continuous-forms

I need to enable or disable a control on a continuous subform, dependent on another field. The initial code I wrote by instinct was very similar to what is suggested [here](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1654808-continuous-form-making-button-visible-invisible.html#post6453487), but instead of only disabling those controls which are marked as "child", it disables all of them - in effect, it seems only to be looking for the value of the last record and affecting all the rows.

Is there a way this can be achieved, or am I barking up the wrong tree? Code below:

```
If Me.Record_Type = "Child" Then 'Disable subsidiary records
Me.Record_Type.SetFocus
Me.Prospect_Name.Enabled = False
End If
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way of sensibly working with rows in a continuous form is with [Conditional Formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/apply-conditional-formatting-to-a-form-template-HA010024057.aspx). Any code applied refers to the active row, and so it appears to affect all rows.

**Conditional Formatting, Access 2010**

Enable / Disable is selected

[image: Conditional Formatting, Access 2010]

Comment: Thanks, will check out the link and report back.

Comment: Hi Remou - conditional formatting works fine for changing colours and the like, but appears to have no abilities over enabling or disabling the control as I want to - I'm beginning to suspect this is impossible, is this the case?

Comment: Hi @OliJeffery The very last option in the row is Enable / Disable. I have just checked for Access 2010, but I remember it from earlier versions. It is a little hard to see.

Comment: Aha! Perfect, thanks. I was being a doofus and assumuing that disabled or enabled the rule as opposed to the control.