# MS Access - conditionally set enabled or disabled for field in datasheet view

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a subform in datasheet view, 2 fields Im working with are 'completed' and 'activity'.
On the form open or load, how can I set 'activit'y for each line in the subform to enabled / disabled depending on whether 'completed' = Y or N?
Any hint appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting for continuous forms and datasheets.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this just set the colour etc of the field? Not the other properties such as locked, enabled etc

Comment: Observe the clicked button beside the text (A) button. It is the enable / disable button. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507151/enabling-and-disabling-controls-on-a-continuous-subform-in-access-2007/11507179#11507179