# Ms Access lock a field based on its current value in continuous (tabular) form

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

[image]

I have a check box named `post` in a continuous (tabular) form i want it to be automatically disabled i.e. locked if `post=true` while the rest of the `post` in the datasheet which are `post=false` remained enabled i.e. unlocked in the visual code builder i tried the following

approach 1

```
If Me.Post = False Or Me.NewRecord Then
    Me.Post.AllowEdits = False
Else
    Me.Post.AllowEdits = True
End If
```

approach 2

```
If Me.Post = True Then
    Me.Post.Locked = True
Else
    Me.Post.Locked = False
End If
```

but none of them worked in scope of the form `Private Sub Form_Loan_Payment()` and when i applied the following

```
If Me.Post = True Then
    Me.Post.Locked = True
Else
    Me.Post.Locked = False
End If
```

In `Private Sub Post_Click()` it disabled all the post in the entire data sheet and it that after the check box was updated and if i reload the form all the post are enabled again

Comment: Did you try the **.Enabled** method?

Comment: Instead of **.Locked** or **.AllowEdits**.  If a control is disabled (Enabled = False), it's essentially locked.

Comment: tried but hat doesnt seem to be working! :(

Comment: @JohnnyBones do i have to do some special action for conditional formatting to work on check boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now that I think about it, you're going to need Conditional Formatting.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507151/enabling-and-disabling-controls-on-a-continuous-subform-in-access-2007-2010) for some ideas and info.

Comment: seems like conditional formatting doesn't work on ext boxes any advices?

Comment: check boxes dont support continious formating but i am choosing this as the answer since it was help for me to reach to the conclusion as for my solution its here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394573/work-around-ms-access-continuous-form/22422876#22422876